# Finding correct variation for $\rho$ in spherical coordinate integration

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am having some trouble and looking for help on calculating the moment of inertia about the z axis of the region bound by the cone $z=\sqrt{3(x^2+y^2)}$ and the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ if the density is inversely proportional to the distance from $z$ axis.

My thoughts:

I think it will come down to evaluating $$\iiint_{D} (x^2+y^2) \frac{K}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dV$$

Where D must be determined from the cone and the sphere. K a constant of proportionality.

My problem is I am not sure which coordinates I should work in and how I should find the appropriate limits of integration.

I was thinking possibly spherical coordinates. If that worked it could seemingly come down to evaluating the triple integral of $\rho^3 \sin(\psi)^2$

I also seemed to find that $tan(\psi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ so that could be used to solve for range of $\psi$. And $\theta$ from $0$ to $2pi$, $\rho$ from $-a$ to $a$? or should it be from $0$ to 
$sqrt{a}$ , I am a bit confused on that to

Can anyone please let me know if any of this is on the right track and if not , some help?

Thank you

Comment: Try breaking the problem down into two pieces: a cone with a flat top that’s parallel to the $xy$-plane and a cap that’s a section of a sphere. You should also be able to take advantage of the radial symmetry about the $z$-axis. Cylindrical coordinates seem natural to me for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spherical coordinates:
$$
D=\{(\rho,\theta,\phi)\;|\;0\le \theta \le 2\pi, 0\le \rho \le a, 0\le \phi \le \pi/6\}
$$
Careful, $\rho$ is always positive, and $a$ is the radius of the sphere. $\tan \phi = 1/\sqrt{3}$ will give you the right angle, as you suggested.

In cylindrical coordinates:
$$
D=\{(r,\theta,z) \;|\;0\le \theta \le 2\pi, 0\le r \le a/2, \sqrt{3}r\le z \le \sqrt{a^2-r^2}\}
$$